# Is it possible to resize a metal view (MTKView()) so its height stretches out the whole screen but the ratio to the width is maintained?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, metal

I am trying to scale my `MTKView()` full screen on an iPhone X and I want to maintain the ratio in regards to the width (I understand that means that some of the side will be cut off).

Can anyone help please?

```
required init(coder: NSCoder) {  
    super.init(coder: coder)  

    device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()  

    configureMetal()  

    createTextureCache()  

    colorPixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm  

    self.framebufferOnly = false  
    self.autoResizeDrawable = false  
    self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit  
    self.contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.main.scale  
    self.drawableSize = CGSize(width: 2320, height: 3088)  
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do -- could you please elaborate?

Comment: I am trying to display the output of the depth camera (640 x 480) as a Metal View on the full screen. In order to do that I need to find a way to scale the MTKView to a height of 3088.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you basically want a Metal equivalent of `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`? i.e., you want to draw the depth image such that it fills the screen while maintaining its aspect ratio? Or is the question how to position a view such that its bounds match the native bounds of the display?

Comment: @warrenm Yes that is exactly what I am looking for. With a normal Preview Layer I was able to achieve it with AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years ago I wrote a class called [EEMetalTextureViewer](https://github.com/eldade/EEMetalTextureViewer) that may be useful for this. It is basically a fast Metal-based pixel data viewer that can take a `CVImageBuffer` or just raw pixel data and put it on the screen for you (it is based on `MTKView`), and that class also supports the various `UIViewContentMode` options.

To be clear, supporting those required manual scaling of the content -- `MTKView` does *not* do that for you automatically.

The sample code I have in there actually demonstrates using a live feed from the camera and presenting it -- that might be a good starting point for you.